# Integración fallida Angular5 y paymentez

Tags: javascript, angular5

enfrento un problema y espero puedan ayudarme, estaré muy agradecido, estoy realizando un botón de pagos en Angular 5, quien nos proveerá del servicio es Paymentez, ellos me ayudan con el siguiente código.

```
<script src="https://cdn.paymentez.com/checkout/1.0.1/paymentez-checkout.min.js"></script>

<button class="js-paymentez-checkout">Comprar licencia Estándar</button>
<div id="response" class=""></div>
<script>
    var paymentezCheckout = new PaymentezCheckout.modal({
        client_app_code: 'PAYMENTEZ_CLIENT_APP_CODE', // Client Credentials Provied by Paymentez
        client_app_key: 'PAYMENTEZ_CLIENT_APP_KEY', // Client Credentials Provied by Paymentez
        locale: 'es', // User's preferred language (es, en, pt). English will be used by default.
        env_mode: 'stg', // `prod`, `stg`, `dev`, `local` to change environment. Default is `stg`
        onOpen: function() {
            console.log('modal open');
        },
        onClose: function() {
            console.log('modal closed');
        },
        onResponse: function(response) { // The callback to invoke when the Checkout process is completed

            /*
              In Case of an error, this will be the response.
              response = {
                "error": {
                  "type": "Server Error",
                  "help": "Try Again Later",
                  "description": "Sorry, there was a problem loading Checkout."
                }
              }

              When the User completes all the Flow in the Checkout, this will be the response.
              response = {  
                "transaction":{  
                    "status":"success", // success or failure
                    "id":"CB-81011", // transaction_id
                    "status_detail":3 // for the status detail please refer to: https://paymentez.github.io/api-doc/#status-details
                }
              }
            */
            console.log('modal response');
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
        }
    });

    var btnOpenCheckout = document.querySelector('.js-paymentez-checkout');
    btnOpenCheckout.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        paymentezCheckout.open({
            user_id: '1234',
            user_email: 'eguillen@paymentez.com', //optional        
            user_phone: '7777777777', //optional
            order_description: '1 Licencia Estándar (IVA y gastos adm. incluidos)',
            order_taxable_amount: 1,
            order_tax_percentage: 12,
            order_amount: 1.12,
            order_vat: 0.12,
            order_reference: '#234323411',
            //order_installments_type: 2, // optional: The installments type are only available for Equador. The valid values are: https://paymentez.github.io/api-doc/#installments-type
            //order_taxable_amount: 0, // optional: Only available for Datafast (Equador). The taxable amount, if it is zero, it is calculated on the total. Format: Decimal with two fraction digits.
            //order_tax_percentage: 10 // optional: Only available for Datafast (Equador). The tax percentage to be applied to this order.
        });
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        paymentezCheckout.close();
    });
</script>
```

es un botón que me presentan un modal, en consola indica cuando se abrió, información del explorador y cuando se cerró sin embargo cuando lo integrarlo a mi aplicación, no hace absolutamente nada, no trae el modal, no escribe en consola, lo mas triste es que ni me muestra ningún error.

Este es mi html con la integración de Paymentez

```
<script src="https://cdn.paymentez.com/checkout/1.0.1/paymentez-checkout.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<!-- Paymentez -->
<link href="https://cdn.paymentez.com/js/ccapi/stg/paymentez.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.paymentez.com/js/ccapi/stg/paymentez.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>

<div class="main-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="card">
                    <!------------------------------------------------Cabecera de la tabla------------------------------------------------>
                    <!------------------------------------------------Cabecera de la tabla------------------------------------------------>
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-12">

                                <div class="row no-gutters">
                                    <h4 class="title col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">Datos de Factura</h4>
                                    <div class="title col-6 col-md-4">Estudiante</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of _pagoOnlineService.datoFacConsul">
                                        <p class="category">NOMBRES Y APELLIDOS:
                                            <input type="text" #representa="ngModel" name="representa" [(ngModel)]="item.representante" class="form-control cabecera">

                                            <p class="category">DIRECCION:
                                                <input type="text" #direc="ngModel" name="direc" [(ngModel)]="item.direccion" class="form-control cabecera">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of _pagoOnlineService.datoFacConsul">
                                        <p class="category">C.I/PASAPORTE:
                                            <input type="text" #cedu="ngModel" name="cedu" [(ngModel)]="item.cedula" class="form-control cabecera">

                                            <p class="category">TELEFONO:
                                                <input type="text" #direc="ngModel" name="direc" [(ngModel)]="item.telefono" class="form-control cabecera">
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let item of _pagoOnlineService.datoRepreConsul">
                                        <p class="category">ESTUDIANTE:<a class="contenido"> {{item.nomalum}}{{item.apealum}} </a>
                                            <p class="category">CODIGO:<a class="contenido"> {{item.cod_alum}} </a>
                                                <br>
                                                <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="actualizar()">
                                                    <span>Actualizar</span>
                                                </a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-content table-responsive">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <a class="btn btn-success" (click)="inicio()">
                                    <i class="material-icons">home</i> Inicio
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                                <a class="btn btn-info" (click)="pagosPendientes()">
                                    <i class="material-icons">search</i> Pagos pendientes
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div *ngIf="!content">
                            <div class="online-init color">
                                <b>Estimado Usuarios</b><br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Para poder realizar pagos por internet de clic en PAGOS PENDIENTES.</li>
                                    <li>Para poder visualizar y verificar los pagos realizados de clic en HISTORIAL PAGOS.</li>
                                    <li>Las matrículas que son al contado y sin descuento podrán realizar el pago por internet.</li>
                                    <li>Al finalizar el pago se enviará una notificación a su correo institucional.</li>
                                </ul>
                                <b>Tarjetas Disponibles:</b><br><br>
                                <b>Usted puede pagar en línea con su tarjeta de crédito en plan corriente o diferido.</b><br><br>
                                <ul>
                                    <li>Diners Club, Discovery, Visa, MasterCard Banco Pichincha. (3 meses sin intereses, desde 6 hasta 48 meses con intereses).</li>
                                    <li>Visa, Mastercad del Banco del Pacifico o cualquier otra tarjeta en plan corriente. (3 y 6 meses sin intereses, desde 9 hasta 48 meses con intereses).</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <div *ngIf="content">
                            <div *ngIf="dl === true">
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead class="text-danger">
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="tbDeu" colspan="4" style="text-align:center; background-color: #50b848;"><b style="color:#fff">Pagos Pendientes</b></th>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="tbDeu" style="text-align:center;">Factura</th>
                                            <th class="tbDeu" style="text-align:center; width: 50%;">Descripcion</th>
                                            <th class="tbDeu" style="text-align:center;">Total</th>
                                            <th class="tbDeu" style="text-align:center;">PAGAR</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr *ngFor="let item of this._pagoOnlineService.deudasList; let in = index">
                                            <td style="text-align:center;"> {{item.CFAC_COD}} </td>
                                            <td> {{item.DESCRIPCION}}, {{item.CFAC_PERI}} </td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center; "> {{item.CFAC_VALOR}} </td>
                                            <td style="text-align:center;">
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <label>
                            <input [(ngModel)]="item.ACCEPT" type="checkbox" [disabled]="item.ACTIVE == false"
                              (change)="checkAll(in)">
                          </label>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                <div class="row" style="float: right;">
                                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                                        <button class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#bd-example-modal-terminos" (click)="pagar()" [disabled]="this._pagoOnlineService.deudasList[0].ACCEPT == false">
                      <i class="material-icons">attach_money</i> Pagar
                    </button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="dl === false">
                                <p class="ndeu">Sus pagos estan al día</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="bd-example-modal-terminos" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="bd-example-modal-verPlanes" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"><b>TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES PARA LA UTILIZACIÓN DEL CANAL BOTON DE
            PAGOS</b></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="">
                    <ol>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>ACEPTACIÓN DEL SERVICIO BOTON.-</b> Pone a disposición de los usuarios el canal de recaudación Botón de Pagos a través de su página Web el mismo que permite realizar las consultas y/o pagos de los servicios prestados
                                en esta empresa. El servicio de recaudación a través de este canal será prestado en adelante el “PRESTADOR” que será brindado a usted usuario en adelante “CLIENTE” bajo los términos y condiciones previstos
                                en el presente contrato. Al ingresar y usar este sitio Web el “CLIENTE” expresa su voluntad y acepta los términos y condiciones establecidos pulsando sobre el recuadro “ACEPTO”, si el “CLIENTE” NO está de acuerdo con estos
                                términos y condiciones no acceda o haga uso de este sitio, por cuanto se entiende que existe un acuerdo en común entre las partes tanto del “PRESTADOR” como por parte del “CLIENTE” para realizar sus consultas y/o pagos
                                de sus planillas de consumo telefónico.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>REGISTRO POR PARTE DEL CLIENTE.-</b> Próximamente el PRESTADOR habilitará este registro para que el CLIENTE pueda acceder a las consultas y/o pagos de los servicios adquiridos a través de la página Web que el “PRESTADOR”
                                pone a su disposición deberá registrarse y proporcionar ciertos datos personales que serán solicitados a fin de poder suministrarle nuestros servicios, el “CLIENTE” brindará toda la información verdadera, precisa y completa,
                                esta información provista por el “CLIENTE” se actualizará a la brevedad. En caso de que el “CLIENTE” proporcione información falsa, imprecisa o incompleta el “PRESTADOR” podrá dar por concluido este contrato. El “CLIENTE”
                                al momento de finalizar el registro se le proporcionará un nombre de inicio de sesión y contraseña y será el responsable de lo que suceda con su nombre de inicio de sesión y contraseña puesto que es el responsable del manejo
                                de su clave y nombre de usuario.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>MODIFICACIONES El “PRESTADOR”.-</b> Podrá modificar cuantas veces sea necesario los términos y condiciones establecidas en este contrato con el fin de aclararlos sin necesidad de formalidad alguna, cada vez que el “PRESTADOR”
                                realice un cambio a estos términos y condiciones serán informados en la página principal debiendo el cliente pulsar sobre el recuadro “ACEPTO” si el cliente no pulsara sobre el recuadro “ACEPTO” se dará por concluido en
                                ese mismo momento, sin incurrir por ello en responsabilidad alguna para el “PRESTADOR”.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>COSTOS.-</b> El “PRESTADOR” en la actualidad ofrece este servicio de manera gratuita, sin que ello limite en un futuro a su modificación, la misma que será notificada a través de esta página Web.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>SERVICIOS.-</b> Los servicios disponibles son los que se encuentran habilitados al momento de su acceso en el sitio Web disponible por el “PRESTADOR”.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>CONFIDENCIALIDAD.-</b> La utilización del canal de recaudación Botón de Pagos que el “PRESTADOR” pone a disposición del “CLIENTE” es de exclusiva responsabilidad del usuario la cual se considera como información privada.
                                El “PRESTADOR” no se hace responsable por el mal manejo de la información proporcionada al “CLIENTE”.
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD.-</b> Por la prestación de este servicio, el “PRESTADOR” podrá recopilar información de registro, información que pasará a terceros cuando ésta sea requerida por la ley o por acciones legales para
                                las cuales ésta información es relevante, como cuando se trate de una orden judicial o a propósito para prevenir un delito o fraude. En cuyo caso se entenderá que el “CLIENTE” ha dado su permiso para revelar la información
                                constante por la ejecución del servicio.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>PROPIEDAD.-</b> El “CLIENTE” acepta que el “PRESTADOR” es el dueño y propietario de los derechos personales y reales sobre la Base de Datos que se proporcionará en este servicio de recaudación.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>TERMINACION.-</b> El “CLIENTE” tiene el derecho de cancelar o finalizar la utilización de este servicio de consultas y/o pagos de sus servicios en cualquier momento. Una vez cancelado el servicio, el “CLIENTE” no tendrá
                                derecho ni podrá seguir utilizando este canal de recaudación, pero podrá utilizar todos los canales de recaudación que dispone el PRESTADOR. El servicio de recaudación a través de la página Web “Botón de Pagos”
                                estará disponible de forma permanente de 8:00 am a las 22:00 pm del día, los 7 días de la semana y durante los 365 días del año. DIA HORARIO SERVICIO lunes a domingo De 8h00 a 22h00 Aclaratoria: los días 5, 12, 19, 26 se
                                habilitará el servicio hasta las 19h00 por procesos de facturación. No obstante, el servicio se podrá interrumpir cuando resulte necesario o conveniente realizar las operaciones de mantenimiento en la red.
                            </p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>INDEMNIDAD.-</b> El “CLIENTE” se obliga a mantener indemnes de todo reclamo o demanda a el “PRESTADOR”, sus accionistas, funcionarios, agentes y empleados, incluyendo honorarios de abogados, hincado por algún tercero debido
                                a, o que surja como consecuencia del uso por parte suya del servicio que se le ha proporcionado, de su violación de los términos y condiciones, o de la violación de algún derecho de un tercero.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>COMERCIAL.-</b> El “CLIENTE” tiene derecho a usar el servicio de consultas y/o pagos de sus servicios como un servicio personal, el “CLIENTE” se obliga además a utilizar responsablemente cada uno de los servicios habilitados.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>PROHIBICIONES.-</b> El “CLIENTE” se obliga a no realizar cualquiera de los siguientes actos. ¸ Fingir ser una persona; ¸ Violar alguna ley nacional a través del, o en el servicio; ¸ Causar molestias o perturbar a terceros
                                a través del, o en el servicio; ¸ Recopilar o almacenar datos de terceros o acerca de ellos; ¸ Utilizar el servicio de alguna forma que no sea lo expresamente permitido; Reproducir, duplicar, copiar vender o explotar con
                                algún fin comercial alguna parte que por uso o acceso se tiene al servicio; Utilizar términos o expresiones injuriosas, intimidantes, calumniantes o contrarias a las buenas costumbres.</p>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <p><b>JURISDICCIÓN Y COMPETENCIA.-</b> La legislación aplicable a este contrato es la ecuatoriana. Para el caso de reclamo con respecto a la relación o ejecución en cumplimiento de las condiciones establecidas en este documento
                                o de la utilización del servicio, incluyendo sin limitación, el reclamo sobre la validez, interpretación, exigibilidad o incumplimiento de dichas condiciones, finalmente será resuelto por los jueces competentes del Cantón
                                Quito, Provincia de Pichincha.</p>
                        </li>
                    </ol>
                </div>
                <!---------------------------------------------------------------------->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
                <button class="js-paymentez-checkout btn btn-success">Aceptar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="response" class=""></div>
<script>
    var paymentezCheckout = new PaymentezCheckout.modal({
        client_app_code: 'ADCOM-EC-CLIENT', // Client Credentials Provied by Paymentez
        client_app_key: 'XbcDMWfFaxJcinscgku63MWfe22WpU', // Client Credentials Provied by Paymentez
        locale: 'es', // User's preferred language (es, en, pt). English will be used by default.
        env_mode: 'stg', // `prod`, `stg`, `dev`, `local` to change environment. Default is `stg`
        onOpen: function() {
            console.log('modal open');
        },
        onClose: function() {
            console.log('modal closed');
        },
        onResponse: function(response) { // The callback to invoke when the Checkout process is completed

            /*
                  In Case of an error, this will be the response.
                  response = {
                    "error": {
                      "type": "Server Error",
                      "help": "Try Again Later",
                      "description": "Sorry, there was a problem loading Checkout."
                    }
                  }

                  When the User completes all the Flow in the Checkout, this will be the response.
                  response = {  
                    "transaction":{  
                        "status":"success", // success or failure
                        "id":"CB-81011", // transaction_id
                        "status_detail":3 // for the status detail please refer to: https://paymentez.github.io/api-doc/#status-details
                    }
                  }
                */
            console.log('modal response');
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
        }
    });

    var btnOpenCheckout = document.querySelector('.js-paymentez-checkout');
    btnOpenCheckout.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        paymentezCheckout.open({
            user_id: '1234',
            user_email: 'eguillen@paymentez.com', //optional        
            user_phone: '7777777777', //optional
            order_description: '1 Licencia Estándar (IVA y gastos adm. incluidos)',
            order_taxable_amount: 1,
            order_tax_percentage: 12,
            order_amount: 1.12,
            order_vat: 0.12,
            order_reference: '#234323411',
            //order_installments_type: 2, // optional: The installments type are only available for Equador. The valid values are: https://paymentez.github.io/api-doc/#installments-type
            //order_taxable_amount: 0, // optional: Only available for Datafast (Equador). The taxable amount, if it is zero, it is calculated on the total. Format: Decimal with two fraction digits.
            //order_tax_percentage: 10 // optional: Only available for Datafast (Equador). The tax percentage to be applied to this order.
        });
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        paymentezCheckout.close();
    });
</script>
```

Pero esa no es toda la tragedia, resulta que si busco mi html y lo abro con doble clic, obviamente mostrándome todo feito y sin datos, justo ahí, el botón si funciona y trae el modal, he intentado todo lo que a mi alcance, pero no entiendo el porqué?.

Sin mas que decir me despido y les agradezco de antemano, Exitos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido llegar a la solución gracias a [Pablo Aispura](https://www.facebook.com/reyfaraoh)

La solución fue usar la librería `postscribe` de la siguiente manera

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import * as postscribe from 'postscribe'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-pago-online',
  templateUrl: './pago-online.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./pago-online.component.scss'],
})
export class PagoOnlineComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    postscribe('#response', `<script>
    var paymentezCheckout = new PaymentezCheckout.modal({
        client_app_code: 'PAYMENTEZ_CLIENT_APP_CODE', // Client Credentials Provied by Paymentez
        client_app_key: 'PAYMENTEZ_CLIENT_APP_KEY', // Client Credentials Provied by Paymentez
        locale: 'es', // User's preferred language (es, en, pt). English will be used by default.
        env_mode: 'stg', // 'prod', 'stg', 'dev', 'local' to change environment. Default is 'stg'
        onOpen: function() {
            console.log('modal open');
        },
        onClose: function() {
            console.log('modal closed');
        },
        onResponse: function(response) { // The callback to invoke when the Checkout process is completed

            /*
                  In Case of an error, this will be the response.
                  response = {
                    "error": {
                      "type": "Server Error",
                      "help": "Try Again Later",
                      "description": "Sorry, there was a problem loading Checkout."
                    }
                  }

                  When the User completes all the Flow in the Checkout, this will be the response.
                  response = {
                    "transaction":{
                        "status":"success", // success or failure
                        "id":"CB-81011", // transaction_id
                        "status_detail":3 // for the status detail please refer to: https://paymentez.github.io/api-doc/#status-details
                    }
                  }
                */
            console.log('modal response');
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
        }
    });

    var btnOpenCheckout = document.querySelector('.js-paymentez-checkout');
    btnOpenCheckout.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // Open Checkout with further options:
        paymentezCheckout.open({
            user_id: '1234',
            user_email: 'eguillen@paymentez.com', //optional
            user_phone: '7777777777', //optional
            order_description: '1 Licencia Estándar (IVA y gastos adm. incluidos)',
            order_taxable_amount: 1,
            order_tax_percentage: 12,
            order_amount: 5,
            order_vat: 0.12,
            order_reference: '#234323411',
        });
    });

    // Close Checkout on page navigation:
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function() {
        paymentezCheckout.close();
    });
</script>`)
  }
```

El primer parámetro del método `postscribe` es el `id` del `div` al que insertaremos el código y el segundo parámetro es el código que insertaremos

Answer (score -3):

Hola ya no uso esa versión antigua de angular pero recuerdo que en Angular 5 debes instalar la librería jquery,lo mejor es crearse un nuevo proyecto para probar, primero instala lo siguiente --->  `npm install jquery --save` luego en tu .ts que vas a usar añade `import * as $ from "jquery";` Todo esto hará que tu Jquery se instale y se importe. Ahora los demás archivos que vayas a utilizar descárgalos y añadelos en tu carpeta assets o como quieras porbarlos y llámalos desde tu html por ejemplo

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery.js"></script>
```

También puedes probar lo que se hicieron en estos hilos : 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51962802/how-to-add-external-jquery-plugin-to-angular-project 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934727/how-to-use-jquery-plugin-with-angular-4

Debería funcionarte en caso que te funcione me poner como respuesta útil.

Comment: Tengo instalado Jquery, ya que lo uso en otros procesos, sin embargo en el proceso que estoy detallado no usa Jquery por ninguna parte.

Comment: Me votaste negativo y te estoy tratando de ayudar ?? bye

Comment: no Xavier, solo hice énfasis en que no se usa Jquery, lamento que tengas ese negativo, pero yo no lo puse. Yo estoy agradecido con cualquier comentario que me hagan.